# SWIG for C++ code to Python , is this the valid way to wrap a std::array the same as a C-style array?

Tags: python, c++, arrays, swig

SWIG newbie here. Let's say I have some typemaps defined for a C-style array:

```
%typemap(in) double[ANY] (double temp[$1_dim0]) {
  ...
}

// Convert from C to Python for c-style arrays
%typemap(out) double [ANY] {
    ...
}
```

If I want these to use this same exact logic for a std::array of doubles instead of a C-style array. However, I am not sure what the correct syntax is for this typemap to apply to an array of arbitrary dimension. Would the following logic be sufficient?

```
%apply double[ANY] { std::array<double, ANY> };
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[SWIG has support for some C++ templates](https://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Library_stl_cpp_library) including `std::array`, but each instance of a template used in an interface must be declared.  For example:

**test.i**

```cpp
%module test

%{
#include <array>
%}

%include <std_array.i>
%template(DoubleArray10) std::array<double, 10>;
%template(DoubleArray5) std::array<double, 5>;

%inline %{
double func(const std::array<double, 10>& arr) {
    double sum = 0.0;
    for(auto n: arr)
        sum += n;
    return sum;
}

std::array<double, 5> outfunc() {
    return {5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
}
%}
```

**Python demo:**

```py
>>> import test
>>> test.func([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
55.0
>>> test.outfunc()
(5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0)
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, but adding an argument to `template()` for the type name seems to do the trick. I'm confused about how this example works without the type name!

Comment: @danny I left the name out because I don't need it from Python, but that might be an undefined behavior depending on SWIG version or compiler.  It worked without it for me but I've added some names.

Comment: @Danny I compared the C++ output file generated from using a template name vs. without and it generates quite a bit more (unused, in my case) code in the named version .  Did you run my exact example or incorporate changes in your own code?  Perhaps how you access the template depends on whether you need a name.